# Getting error when accessing the variable from service

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. I am facing an issue while login.

login.php

```
 $email = $password = "";
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {          
   $email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_var($_POST["password"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    require_once './Model/Member.php';
    $member = new Member();
    $isValidLogin = $member->loginMember($email, $password);   
    if($isValidLogin==true) // getting the exception here
    {
      // redirect to dashboard page                                     
    } else{
      // Invalid login                              
    }
}
```

Member Service

```
public function loginMember($email, $password)
{
        $loginUserResult = $this->ValidateUser($email, $password);
        return $loginUserResult;
}
```

When I click on the login button, I am getting the following error message:

```
Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: where `$email` and `$password` is declare?

Comment: Which line throws the error, precisely?

Comment: @ADyson: Its in login page. I have mentioned the exact line in the form of comment.

Comment: @KhajaMoinuddin Are you sure? I think that's impossible because `$isValidLogin` is probably a boolean (am I right?) and anyway you're not trying to treat it like an array of access an index within it. You can't get an error about an array on a line where you're not using any array syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a variable as an array while it is a null (most possibly not declared/instantiated). An example is :

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; // you expect $_SERVER to be an array and have a key 'REQUEST_METHOD'. $_SERVER is most probably not throwing an error as this can be expected to be set.
$_POST['email']; // you expect $_POST to be an array that has 'email' as a key. This is most likely your culprit, as this variable is null when you have no post.
```

To avoid this error being thrown, check if the variables are indeed set and if they are an array before using it as an array.

```
if(is_array($_POST))
{
    if(isset($_POST['email']))
    //do something
}
```

If you don't have a post as your form action, it will be obvious as your form will post the variables using a GET, which will most likely put the variables in your url (eg. [www.example.com/login?email=user@example.com](http://www.example.com/login?email=user@example.com))

Comment: I have the post as the  form action.

Comment: With the added info from your edit, it seems your loginMember() method is the culprit, as the line you claim throws the error can't possibly cause it. Can you show the code in the ValidateUser() method?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. Finally I have found the solution:

In the Validate Method:

```
$loginUserResult = $this->getMember($email);
```

Here the $loginUserResult is coming null and in the very next line, we are trying to access email:

```
$loginUserResult[0]["email"]
```

We have to add the null exceptional handling to resolve the issue.

Comment: @stef: Thanks for your help!

Comment: When I debug the code, the exception did not occur in member service but in login.php. Its weird.